# How can I add IgnorePath for yuidoc

Tags: yuidoc

While generating document form yuidoc I want to ignore downloaded javascript libraries inside lib folder of my project. How can I place that into ignore list
I tried
    `"ignorePaths": [ "./lib" ]`,
    `"ignorePaths": [ "./lib/*.js" ]`,
    `"ignorePaths": [ "lib" ]`

still it's compiles my javascript library files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try using the `exclude` option as discussed here https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/issues/5

`"exclude" : ["lib"]`

Comment: The `exclude` option seems to take a string not an array as its value. YUIDoc calls `string.split` to get the paths.

Comment: From the official doc: "Specify a comma separated list of names you want to `exclude` from parses when YUIDoc recurses the source tree."

Answer (score 0):

*I'm adding an answer with a little more detail since I ran into this problem yesterday and it could be helpful to someone else.*

As @slolife mentioned, you should be using `"exclude"`.

The value for `"exclude"` needs to be a **String** of comma separated directories (not Array).  This can be done via your JSON config file as one of the `"options"` or as a command-line argument.

## Single Directory Examples

**JSON Config File**

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "options": {
        "exclude": "lib"
    }
}
```

**Command-line**

```
yuidoc . -x "lib"
```

## Multiple Directories Examples

***NOTE:*** NO spaces between directories in the list

**JSON Config File**

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "options": {
        "exclude": "lib,lib2"
    }
}
```

**Command-line**

```
yuidoc . -x "lib","lib2"
```

*Reference: http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/args/index.html*